# Using ng-options with ng-changed in select form input

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a select widget using Angular's ng-options. I have this so far:

```
<select id="id_question" name="question" ng-model="post.Question"
    ng-options="question.id as question.title for question in questions"
    ng-change="updateFields(post.Question)" required>
</select>
```

I need an object passed through as a parameter to the 'updateFields' method. However, due to the ng-options using the 'id', this is not possible.

How do I retain using id as the value in the select widget but also have the ability to pass the 'question' object as a parameter in ng-change?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to pass complete object to your function if you are using ng-options. Instead what you can do is set your ng-model to some other property and use that property to assign value to your post.Question variable.

```
<select name="question" ng-model="selectedValue"
        ng-options="question as question.title for question in questions"
        ng-change="updateFields(selectedValue)" required>
</select>
```

in JS

```
    $scope.updateFields = function(question) {

       $scope.id = $scope.selectedvalue.id;
        console.log(question);
  }
```

Please have a look at [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CD7y5VVrP1IrzdAyzITW)

Answer (score 1):

When ever you use ng-model for a select element you need not pass the selected object as a event parameter in ng-change.

Have a look at the below code

```
$scope.updateFields=function(){
      console.log($scope.selectedQuestion);
    }
```

Your HTML must be as

```
<select name="question" ng-model="selectedQuestion"
    ng-options="question as question.title for question in questions"
    ng-change="updateFields()" required>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/WFGzylowbayNsaxLTs1a?p=preview)**

Assumed json

```
$scope.questions=[
    {title:'A',id:1},
    {title:'Abcdef',id:4}];
```

Comment: The item is part of a dynamic ng-form. It is a subelement of a large form using ng-repeat so it can be added/removed dynamically. Therefore, it probably can't be accessed easily in scope. So I used a parameter in this case..

Comment: yes but the **ng-model = selectedQuestion** corresponds to this select statement only. Also your post does not convey the **ng-repeat**